# Can I specify S3 bucket for sagemaker.sklearn.estimator's SKLearn?

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-s3, scikit-learn, amazon-sagemaker

I'm following this example notebook to learn SageMaker's processing jobs API: https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker_processing/scikit_learn_data_processing_and_model_evaluation/scikit_learn_data_processing_and_model_evaluation.ipynb

I'm trying to modify their code to avoid using the default S3 bucket, namely: `s3://sagemaker-<region>-<account_id>/`

For their data processing step with the `.run` method:

```
from sagemaker.processing import ProcessingInput, ProcessingOutput

sklearn_processor.run(
    code="preprocessing.py",
    inputs=[ProcessingInput(source=input_data, destination="/opt/ml/processing/input")],
    outputs=[
        ProcessingOutput(output_name="train_data", source="/opt/ml/processing/train"),
        ProcessingOutput(output_name="test_data", source="/opt/ml/processing/test"),
    ],
    arguments=["--train-test-split-ratio", "0.2"],
)
```

I was able to modify it to use my own S3 bucket by using the `destination` parameter like this:

```
sklearn_processor.run( 
    code=output_bucket_uri + "preprocessing.py", 
    inputs=[ProcessingInput( 
        source=input_bucket_uri + "census-income.csv", 
        destination=path+"input/", 
    )], 
    outputs=[ 
        ProcessingOutput( 
            output_name="train_data", 
            source=path+"train/", 
            destination=output_bucket_uri + "train/", 
        ), 
        ProcessingOutput( 
            output_name="test_data", 
            source=path+"test/", 
            destination=output_bucket_uri + "test/", 
        ), 
    ], 
    arguments=["--train-test-split-ratio", "0.2"], 
)
```

But for the `.fit` method:

```
sklearn.fit({"train": preprocessed_training_data})
```

I have not been able to find a parameter to pass it so that the output artifacts are saved to a S3 bucket that I specify instead of the default s3 bucket `s3://sagemaker-<region>-<account_id>/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SKLearnProcessor, the ideal way to specify default bucket is by creating a sagemaker session with that bucket, and sending that as sagemaker_session parameter. Example:

```
from sagemaker.session import Session    
sklearn_processor = SKLearnProcessor(framework_version='0.20.0',
                                     role='<arn-role>',
                                     instance_type='ml.m5.xlarge',
                                     instance_count=1,
                                     sagemaker_session=Session(default_bucket='<s3-bucket-name>'))
```

I know this is not your exact question but you have added an alternative to this in your question details. So I am adding it here as a cleaner approach.

Comment: Thanks; I wish I can verify this but I no longer have the environment readily available. I’ll take your word for it. Thank you for offering the cleaner approach.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps others...

To get `.fit()` to output to a designated S3 bucket, I ended configuring the estimator with `output_path`.

Here's the example code:

```
from sagemaker.sklearn.estimator import SKLearn 

sklearn = SKLearn( 
    entry_point="../processor/code/train.py", 
    output_path=output_bucket_uri, 
    framework_version="0.20.0", 
    instance_type="ml.m5.xlarge", 
    role=role, 
)
sklearn.fit({"train": preprocessed_training_data})
```

Here's the docs relating to the base estimator class: https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/estimators.html